# Want to display VAT price on Shopping and Checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, vat

I have a product, who's price is 299GBP (UK), and vat for it is 49.83GBP. I want it to be displayed on checkout page and shopping page. 
The vat price is displayed in the price section of "Manage Products"correctly(i.e on the Admin backend)
but it is not displaying on the frontend.

Plz help...

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System->Configuration->Tax->Shopping Cart Display Settings** and set the field **Display Prices** to **Including tax**.

Comment: It displays VAT(20%), but the VAT amount is wrong...my product price is 299 for which VAT is 49.83, but it displays 0.83!! Plz help